# How to pass complex data structures (example: a vector with many elements) between service and the remote binder?

Tags: android

The object passing between an Android service and the remote binder is happening through serialization of the object.  If the service needs to return a very large collection, it seems very inefficient to use this. What is the recommended way to deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Android you should implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) rather than `Serializable` on your objects, as the performance is much better.  Your AIDL method can then specifiy a `Parcel` as an argument.

[Here's the SDK documentation about passing `Parcelable` objects to a `Service`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html#parcelable) which has some sample code.